# How to Fetch JSON data from GET Request FLASK-Python

Tags: json, reactjs, flask, get, create-react-app

I am using a get request on a react app to run a function that so far just "prints" out data in my flask api. I can hit the endpoint, and receive back a "response", but I am not sure how to attach the JSON data to the response given by FLASK.

PS: Is it required to post this JSON data to a database and then retreive it from my create react app? Or can I do what I am tryinig to do, which is to simply run the GET request, have it produce JSON, and then ship it back to the Create React App in the GET response.

**Flask API (views.py)**

```
@main.route('/add_post')
def add_post():
  

  temparray = []
  *code that pushes json object into temparray [{}, {}, {}]*
  
  time.sleep(5)       
  post_data = temparray
  print (post_data)

  ^^^^^^How do I attach post_data to the response?^^^^^^^^^
  

  return 'Done', 201
```

**Create React App (app.js)**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/add_post").then(response =>
      console.log(response)
      )
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        test
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In here,

```js
fetch("/add_post").then(response =>
  console.log(response)
)
```

Do this instead

```
fetch("/add_post")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonData => {
    // do something with the data, e.g. setState
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return post_data` from your `add_post` function. This will automatically convert a valid dict to JSON (i.e. [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify))

Comment: I think this has gotten me a step further. I am now receiving the error 
Error Reading data SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0.
I have tried quite a few solutions to fix this, but no luck so far.

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the data generation, could be a different problem/question though

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. Thank you for your assistance.